# Equations involving orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonality

My variables are: $O_1,\dots,O_M\in \mathbb{O}(d)$

I have equations like:

$O_{1_1} x_{1,1}+ \dots + O_{1_{m_1}} x_{1,m_1} = x_{1,(m_1+1)}$

$\vdots$

$O_{n_1} x_{n,1}+ \dots + O_{n_{m_n}} x_{n,m_n} = x_{n,(m_n+1)}$

$i_j \in [1,M]$ and $x_{i,j}\in \mathbb{R}^d$ are constants.

My question is:

What is the value of $n$ such that the above equations have a unique solution?

**My guess:** $n$ is related to the dimension of $\mathbb{O}(d)$.

Comment: These equations are independent, so the problem is how to solve the first one $O_{1_1} x_{1,1}+ \dots + O_{1_{m_1}} x_{1,m_1} = x_{1,(m_1+1)}$ Is that right (the others being of the same "caliper") ?

Comment: I think we can not solve the first equation uniquely because there are $d$ equations and the number of variables are more.

Comment: Maybe there is an ambiguity in my understanding : what do you mean for example by $O_{1_k}$. I thought a short time that it was  the $k$-th column of $O_{1}$.. . But this is not the case... this **subindex** notation is very troubling. Moreover, I have a problem of dimensions : unless $O_{i_j}$ is a scalar, the dimensions of the LHSides and RHSides do not agree...

Comment: No. $O_{i_j}$ denotes any one among $O_1, \dots , O_M$.

Comment: $x_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is given

Comment: " $O_{i_j}$   denotes any one among $O_1, \cdots O_M$  ". Waoh. This interpretation is not evident at all. You **have to** say it in your question. Second question : when you say "any" : which permutation of indices should be taken ?

Comment: I am sorry (it is my last remark before leaving) but in my humble opinion, your question is so general that the most probable is that unless you simplify it, for example by taking a $3 \times 3$ system as an example, nobody will be able to answer it.

Comment: Okay, let consider the case for $\mathbb{O}(2)$. I have the similar equations, then how many equations do I need?

Comment: Ok for $\mathbb{O}(2)$. If you have $O_1X_1+O_2X_2=X_3$, as orthogonal matrices preserve norms, first of all, it induces a condition : $\|X_3\| \leq \|X_1\|+\|X_2\|$. Do you assume that this is always the case ?